# Code Highlighting in BlockQuote

Tags: code, syntax-highlighting

Many of my Wordpress Blog(http://subinsb.com/) posts have code snippets which is wrapped in **blockquote** elements. I need to highlight these code snippets. I tried using **GeSHi**, **Prettify Code Syntax**, **CodeColorer** but none of them works for **blockquote** elements. Is there any plugin that supports code highlighting for **blockquotes** ?

OR

How can I customize the current highlighting plugins to highlight blockquote elements too ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should use the standard `pre` and `code` elements instead of blockquotes. But if have too many to change them, there might be a workaround.

If you only use blockquotes for code, then you can use a bit of jQuery to convert those to `pre` tags, but make sure to do that before Prettify is loaded.

I don't know how the plugins work, but I can help you do it directly with Prettify.

Download it from [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/downloads/list) and enqueue it on your website.

Then use this jQuery to convert `blockquote` to `pre` and trigger Prettify.

```
$("blockquote").replaceWith(function() { return "<pre>" + $(this).html() + "</pre>"} );
prettyPrint();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to highlight codes with blockquote elements.
Go to **Wordpress Template Editor** (Appearance -> Editor)

Add the following line just above **</head>**

```
<script src='https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/prettify.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<link href='https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/prettify.css' rel='stylesheet'></script>
<script>jQuery(".site-content").ready(function(){jQuery("blockquote").each(function(){jQuery(this).html(prettyPrintOne(jQuery(this).html()));});});</script>
```